# zsh keybinding: ignore given command in insert-last-word

Tags: zsh, keyboard-shortcuts

In `zsh`, I have <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> bound to `insert-last-word`.

When I press <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd>, I can list through the last word of previous commands.

How can I exclude some words from being shown when I cycle through ?

ie, if this is my history:

```
echo
foo
ls
```

and I want to ignore `foo`, then <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> should skip `foo`.

Comment: On what basis do you want to ignore that `foo`? Because it's `foo` (do you want to be able to specify a blacklist of exact words or of patterns as an array for instance), or because it's the second last one or because it's not a valid command? ... ?

Comment: @Stéphane Chazelas - I want to be able to specify a blacklist of exact words or patterns

Comment: I keep researching into your issue and your post is the only thing that comes back as relevant. None of the zsh docs or add-ons mention anything about this behavior. Is there a specific reason for this? It is pulling from your history so you could look at clearing your history and making sure not to call `foo` again? If that is not a solution why specifically does `foo` need to be ignored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’ve tested this and it works:

```bsh
setopt EXTENDED_GLOB
bindkey '^[.' insert-last-word
autoload smart-insert-last-word
zle -N insert-last-word smart-insert-last-word
zstyle :insert-last-word match '*~(*last*|match)'
```

What this does:

1. Replaces `insert-last-word` implementation with the function [`smart-insert-last-word`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/User-Contributions.html#Widgets), which is distributed with Zsh, but not loaded by default.
2. Says that we want our new `insert-last-word` widget to match any word (`*`), but *not* any word that contains the word `last` or the literal word `match`.
3. [`EXTENDED_GLOB`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Operators) is required to be able to use the `~` ("but not") operator.

Of course, it's up to you to replace that pattern in the last line with something that excludes all the words or patterns that you never want to be inserted.